# MySQL deleting expired values

Tags: php, mysql, email, passwords

I'm currently trying to make a forgot password system, where it sends the user and email with a reset token. The user then uses the reset token to reset their password. In reality the reset token will be set to expire(during testing I make it expire in 1 minute after the sending of the email).

In my forgot password php file I have this right before the sending of the email(note that $token is the token that was issued):

```
$query2 = $con->prepare("UPDATE UserName SET resetkey = '$token', expire = NOW() + INTERVAL 1 MINUTE WHERE userName = :user");
$query2->bindParam(':user',$username);
$query2->execute();
```

Then in my password reset php file I have this right they reset their passwords. It basically purges all expired values so the table won't have an expired value:

```
$purge = $con->prepare("UPDATE UserName SET resetkey = NULL WHERE expires < NOW()");
$purge->execute();
```

The problem I run into is that the user can still reset his password even if the token he enters is expired. I made sure the timing is correct(and I even waited 5 minutes just to be sure). The token should expire in a minute though.
Can anyone explain to me why that's happening?
Thanks!

Comment: You should also set resetkey to null where resetkey = '$token'. This is missing in your design. Don't forget to real_escape the $token to prevent sql injection.

Comment: It sounds like you're only deleting the expired tokens *after* the token has been verified.  Make sure you perform the steps in the right order!

Comment: @YusufMoola What's real_escape? I've heard of sql injection and I'm using PDO queries.

Comment: Having used error checking/exceptions, would have signaled the unexisting column. Add `$con->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);` right after the connection is opened.

Comment: PDO calls it $con->quote($token). You should rather pass token as a param that you bind exactly like :user

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your first query, you are using the column name "expire". In your second query you are using the column name "expires".

Comment: Ah, thanks, that was my problem. I'm coding this in Notepad++, so are there any php ides or code editors you can recommend me. Thanks!

Comment: @KevinShen: At the time, I didn't have a good recommendation for you. Now I'm using [PHP Storm](https://www.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/) and find it quite usable.

Answer (score 2):

I think arcodesign gave already the correct answer, but i wonder why you solved it this way. For my projects i always create a separate table with the `token-hash`, the `user-id` and the `creation-date` of the reset entry.

**token-hash:** There you store a hash of the token, not the token itself. Otherwise an attacker with read access to the database (SQL-injection) could demand a password reset for any e-mail address he likes, and because he can see the new token, he could use it to set his own password.

**user-id:** With using a separate table, you are free to just delete the row if the reset expired, or you can leave it and tell the user to demand a new reset.

**creation-date:** I would store the creation date (just `NOW()`) instead of the expiry date, the application can then decide if this date expired. You could also change the period a reset link is valid without migrating the existing rows.

Perhaps you want to have a look at my [password-reset](http://www.martinstoeckli.ch/php/php.html#passwordreset) class, which helps with building such tokens.